# How can I reuse objects without depending on prefabs?

Tags: unity

I have several "frames" in a scene, each frame holds a different image.

These frames all hold the same scripts and are in a way instances of the same concept, but the image is different in each frame.

I want to find a solution for reusability. If I make a change in the hierarchy or add a script to the frame, I don't want to have to go through all the frames and make the same change.

The prefab system works for this case in all ways but one:

There are desirable differences between the frames that I want to keep (the image for instance). But if I make a change to one frame, and click the "Apply" button, all the settings of the current frame will apply to all other frames, including the ones that are desirable.

Is there a solution for this other than "Be careful not to click the Apply button" ?

Comment: Are you aware that since Unity 2018.3, [you can edit a prefab directly without requiring an instance of it in the scene](https://unity.com/prefabs)? If you do that, then any properties you have overridden in the prefab instances (like the image) should stay the way they are.

Comment: This solution still leaves the door open for mistakes.

I'll still have to edit instances of the prefab, and while doing so, clicking the "Apply" button by mistake will still do damage.

Comment: That's not strictly true. Any instance that's overridden the changed parameter (like the image) should retain its local override, rather than changing to match the image of the one you clicked "Apply" on.

Comment: @Zephram I can confirm, I've been using Unity for some time, and whenever you edit an instance of a prefab, its new value is not applied to the prefab itself. This means that for any change that should affect all instances, you can edit the prefab itself, and for every "exception" you can edit each instance.

Comment: It's looking like the answer here is "prefabs already do the thing you want to do without prefabs, so just use prefabs" - can you exhibit a specific case where that's not sufficient for your needs?